# Bind Tooltip Visibility to variable so that it shows text conditionally in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tooltip

If I have a class that holds a static variable that will contain the Visiblity status of a Tooltip, how would I write the code-behind to dynamically change the Tooltip visiblity when the visiblity variable changes?

i.e. When Tooltip option is disabled, no Tooltips should be shown, but when Tooltip option is enabled, Tooltips should show up. (Tooltip option is held in a static variable in a different class) The Tooltip and the control it is connecting onto are dynamically created.

Pseudocode:

```
 ToolTip myToolTip = new ToolTip();
 Visiblity tooltipVis = Visibility.Visible;
 Bind myToolTip.Visiblity to toolTipVis
 //Any control with ToolTip should now show their respective ToolTip messages.
 ...
 tooltipVis = Visibility.Hidden;
 //Any control with ToolTip should now have ToolTip messages disabled
```

Attempt at binding to TreeViewItem:

```
 TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem() { Header = tviHeader };
 ToolTip x = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
 x.Content = "This is text.";
 Binding binder = new Binding { 
      Source = EnvironmentalVariables.ToolTipVisibility,
      Path = new PropertyPath("Visibility")
 };
 x.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty, binder);
 user.ToolTip = x;

 public class EnvironmentalVariables {
      public static Visibility ToolTipVisibility { get; set; }
 }
```

This doesn't seem to bind the Visiblity to the EnvironmentalVariables.ToolTipVisibility variable.

Comment: @LPL Not unless you're talking about building a template. I'm sticking to what I know better, hence the code-behind, but if its somehow possible to do it from XAML, I'm all for it.

Comment: Any reason your `ToolTipVisibility` is static? If not, you can switch it back to normal, make it fire `PropertyChanged` and work with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ToolTipService.IsEnabled Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.isenabled) for this.

```
<TextBlock Text="Example" ToolTip="This is an example"
           ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding TooltipEnabled, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">
```

Because you can't bind to a static property ([in WPF Version 4.5 you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29#static_properties)) I would use this workaround to access the property from everywhere

```
public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _tooltipEnabled;
    public bool TooltipEnabled
    {
        get { return _tooltipEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (_tooltipEnabled != value)
            {
                _tooltipEnabled = value;
                RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("TooltipEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to implement this? The reason its a static is because its used across multiple projects and I don't want to create an instance of it in every location.

Comment: I ended up using an INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance on a Singleton to achieve what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `Path` property in the `Binding` object you create.
That's all it needs to work.

```
  EnvironmentalVariables.ToolTipVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

  var b = new Button () { Content = "test" };
  var x = new ToolTip();
  x.Content = "This is text.";
  var binding = new Binding {
    Source = EnvironmentalVariables.ToolTipVisibility,
  };
  x.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty, binding);
  b.ToolTip = x;
```

If you want to change the ToolTipVisibility dynamically at runtime you have to implement a property notification though.

Comment: How would I build the property notification? Since EnvironmentalVariables.ToolTipVisibility is a static.

Comment: You could change the class EnvironmentalVariables to work with the Singleton pattern. That way you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the singleton instance. You can Access the property like that e.g. EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipVisibility.